# Are there any extensions to TADOQuery that include client indexes

Tags: delphi, indexing, ado, delphi-2006

Quick question (hopefully)

I have a large dataset (>100,000 records) that I would like to use as a lookup to determine existence or non-existence of multiple keys. The purpose of this is to find FK violations before trying to commit them to the database to try and avoid the resultant EDatabaseError messing up my transaction.

I had been using TClientDataSet/TDatasetProvider with the FindKey method, as this allowed a client-side index to be set up and was faster (2s to scan each key rather than 10s for ADO). However, moving to large datasets the population of the CDS is starting to take far more time than the local index is saving.

I see that I have a few options for alternatives:

- client cursor with TADOQuery.locate method
- ADO SELECT statements for each check (no client cache)
- ADO SEEK method
- Extend TADOQuery to mimic FindKey

The Locate method seems easiest and doesn't spam the server with the SELECT/SEEK methods. I like the idea of extending the TADOQuery, but was wondering whether anyone knew of any ready-made solutions for this rather than having to create my own?

Comment: In a network environment, the database is the only reliable source. So I'd recommend not to circumvent the transaction.

Comment: I'm not trying to circumvent the transaction, but if I get an EDatabaseError because of a FK violation I'll have to rollback a (potentially large) transaction. If I catch the FK violation myself then I can skip the record and log it, allowing the rest of the records to be imported.

Comment: Is there a multiuser (direct) access  to the database?

Comment: In theory, yes, in practice no - the single accessing app has a lock that prevents other people running it while this process is going on. Not pretty, but it's what I've inherited.

Comment: What database server are you using? Is there any reason why you can not do this with a stored procedure?

Comment: If you'd try to implement an optimistic caching Adodataset1.Recordset.Find() may be the fasted way to do so. You would have to call   Adodataset1.Resync([rmExact,rmCenter]); before accesing the dataset itself again.

Comment: If you're on D2006, have a look at http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/26575.  It fixes the performance problems with TClientDataset scaling, which seems to be at the root of your entire issue.

Comment: Won't cloning work? http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29416

Comment: @ Jan: Cloning will just give me another dataset without an index.

Comment: @Mason: I was actually using MidasSpeedFix, but it appears that it wasn't working properly when using the DLL rather than MidasLib. No idea why, as the author suggests it should be OK with either. The transfer has now come back to 10s from ~200s or so. I still think that having a client-based index helper that works with an ADODataset would be faster than either solution, so I'll leave it open for now to see whether anyone knows of anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a temporary table in the database server. Insert all 100,000 records into this temp table. Do bulk inserts of say 3000 records at a time, to minimise round trips to the server. Then run select statements on this temp table to check for foreign key violations etc. If all okay, do an insert SQL from the temp table to the main table.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, would require too much refactoring for what I'm looking to do now (classic Big Ball of Mud problem), but will bear in mind if I get to spend another large chunk of time in this section of the code.